# apt options within configuration files

Tags: 16.04, apt

i am executing `apt-get` as follows:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*'
apt-get clean
apt-get --option Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get --yes --option Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" --option Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" upgrade
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get --yes --option Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" --option Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" dist-upgrade
apt-get autoremove --yes --force-yes
apt-get clean
```

i would like to remove the options to a configuration file at `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` so the commands could be executed without specifying these options and they will still be honored. namely, i would like to remove:

1. `--option Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false` from `apt-get update`
2. `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` and `--yes --option Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" --option Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold"` from `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get dist-upgrade`
3. `--yes --force-yes` from `apt-get autoremove`

and although i looked at the [manual pages](https://linux.die.net/man/5/apt.conf), i couldn't figure out how to do it correctly.

i would appreciate a detailed explanation how it can be achieved.

in case it is needed, here is some information about my system:

```
$ cat /etc/*release* | grep -i dist
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"

$ dpkg -l | grep -i apt | head -n 1
ii  apt  1.2.15ubuntu0.2  amd64  commandline package manager
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the `--option` parts without `=` to the file:

```
Acquire::Check-Valid-Until "false";
Dpkg::Options:: "--force-confdef";
Dpkg::Options:: "--force-confold";
```

As for `--yes` and `--force-yes`, the [`apt-get` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) says:

```
-y, --yes, --assume-yes
   Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and
   run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as
   changing a held package, trying to install a unauthenticated
   package or removing an essential package occurs then apt-get will
   abort. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.

--force-yes
   Force yes; this is a dangerous option that will cause apt to
   continue without prompting if it is doing something potentially
   harmful. It should not be used except in very special situations.
   Using force-yes can potentially destroy your system! Configuration
   Item: APT::Get::force-yes. This is deprecated and replaced by
   --allow-downgrades, --allow-remove-essential,
   --allow-change-held-packages in 1.1.
```

So:

```
APT::Get::Assume-Yes "true";
APT::Get::force-yes "true";
```

The second line you should replace with lines setting one or more of `APT::Get::allow-downgrades`, `APT::Get::allow-remove-essential`, `APT::Get::allow-change-held-packages` to true.

`DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` is a debconf setting and should be set in `debconf.conf`. The [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man5/debconf.conf.5.html) has examples.

I strongly suggest you write a script instead of setting these in configuration files. Also, there's no point to running an `upgrade` before the `dist-upgrade` - the `dist-upgrade` alone is enough.

Comment: thank you for the answer! is there a specific file within `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` which i should append these lines into or should i create a new one (and if so, what is the file name convention)?

Comment: @MrRoth create a new one. The requirements are given in point 2 of the Description in http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man5/apt.conf.5.html

Comment: thank you again. if that is not much to ask, could you **please** also post a snippet of the relevant part of the `debconf.conf` that corresponds to the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`?

Comment: i created a file named `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99custom-attributes` and placed `APT::Get::` and `Acquire::` configuration there, when i add the `Dpkg::Options` to the same file and then running `apt-get update` i get the error message `E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99custom-attributes:2: Extra junk after value`. what am i missing? :(

Comment: @MrRoth oh, looks like I forgot a `;` after the dpkg option

Comment: correct! thank you (how did i miss it?!?)

Comment: could you please work your magic with a snippet for `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`?

Comment: @MrRoth as for debconf, I don't have a system on hand to test that, so I'll add that later

Comment: *THANK YOU*. will be patiently waiting for that!